# Spring Boot REST application with Jackson - how to handle arbitrary/unknown xml structures passed in?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, spring-boot

I am working with a Spring Boot REST application. We are using jackson to handle  deserialization of XML as well as JSON passed in the request body. An example of   an expected request body looks like this:

```
<formInput><formNum>999999</formNum><documentData>Completely unknown data structure here!</documentData></formInput>
```

In the documentData element, we will have a structure that is completely arbitrary/unknown on the server side. We don't care about the structure, because we only want to pass the xml that is nested in documentData on to another service.

The POJO that we are trying to map the request body onto looks like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=FormInputJsonDeserializer.class)
public class FormInput {

    private String formNum
    private String documentData

    public String getFormNum() {
        return formNum
    }

    public void setFormNum(String formNum) {
        this.formNum = formNum
    }

    public String getDocumentData() {
        return documentData;
    }

    public void setDocumentData(String documentData) {
        this.documentData = documentData;
    }

}
```

The custom JsonDeserializer that we are trying to write:

```
public class FormInputJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<FormInput> {
    @Override
    public FormInput deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {       

        FormInput formInput = new FormInput();

        String fieldName
        JsonToken currentToken
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            currentToken = parser.getCurrentToken()
            if (currentToken.equals(JsonToken.END_OBJECT)) {
                continue
            }

            fieldName = parser.getCurrentName()

            // formNum handling not written yet

            if ("documentData".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldName)) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.START_OBJECT)) {
                    // we are at the start of documentData, and we need to capture the
                    // entire documentData node as a String since we don't know
                    // its structure
                    JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory()
                    StringWriter jsonStringWriter = new StringWriter()
                    JsonGenerator jGen = jfactory.createGenerator(jsonStringWriter)
                    jGen.copyCurrentStructure(parser) // points to END_OBJECT after copy
                    jGen.close()
                    String documentDataJsonStr = jsonStringWriter.getBuffer().toString()
                    println("documentDataJsonStr: " + documentDataJsonStr)
                }
            }
        }

        // rest of code omitted
    }

}
```

As I say, if the request body is xml, ideally I'd like to just keep it formatted as xml and assign that to the documentData String property. However I came up with the above custom deserialization code by following some other examples on StackOverflow. This parsing code ends up converting documentData to a JSON formatted String. Since I didn't know how to pass through the raw XML and get it mapped to the String property, I thought I could just convert the JSON formatted String back to a XML formatted String. A problem arises when we pass in a XML structure like this:

```
<formInput><formNum>9322</formNum><documentData><repeatLevel><subForm1><GROSS_DISTR>    13,004.31</GROSS_DISTR><GROSS_DISTR>    13,004.31</GROSS_DISTR><GROSS_DISTR>    13,004.31</GROSS_DISTR></subForm1></repeatLevel><repeatLevel><subForm1><GROSS_DISTR>    38,681.37</GROSS_DISTR><GROSS_DISTR>    38,681.37</GROSS_DISTR><GROSS_DISTR>    38,681.37</GROSS_DISTR></subForm1></repeatLevel></documentData></formInput>
```

After documentData is parsed in the deserialize method, the println statement shows the parsed JSON String as:

```
{"repeatLevel":{"subForm1":{"GROSS_DISTR":"    13,004.31","GROSS_DISTR":"    13,004.31","GROSS_DISTR":"    13,004.31"}},"repeatLevel":{"subForm1":{"GROSS_DISTR":"    38,681.37","GROSS_DISTR":"    38,681.37","GROSS_DISTR":"    38,681.37"}}}
```

This is actually not strictly valid JSON, due to the duplicate keys. I would have hoped that these would have been converted to JSON arrays, but that is not the case. So, I am unable to turn around and use something like the JSON.org libraries (JsonObject and XML) to convert the JSON String back to XML format (get an exception with a "duplicate key" error).

Does anybody have any suggestions or strategies for handling our situation?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that these are actually Groovy classes, so that is why semi-colons are omitted many places.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a JSONObject, add the @JsonIgnoreProperties("documentData") tag and extract documentData seperately from the raw data using `substring()`